# how to install Powershell Community Extensions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install the PowerShell Community Extensions in PowerShell, but cannot find the installer or the modules anywhere

I have downloaded the archive from https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pscx

but this includes only the source code and no modules or installer...and when extracted just looks like this:

[image]

so where do I get the installer, or the modules from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after further investigation it turns out that PSCX is hosted now on the [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).. so I only needed the *Install-Module* cmdlet, and following the instructions [here](https://winaero.com/blog/fix-install-module-missing-powershell/), it turns out that I needed to install **Windows Management Framework 5.1**, which includes PowerShell 5.1. It has the Install-Module cmdlet

After installing that, I could execute

```
Install-Module Pscx -Scope CurrentUser
```

and this installed PSCX